# Adding over range; how to?

Tags: python, pandas

This seem like a simple task, but I simply cannot get it right!

From the example data, I need to get a deduction for each of the ranges (there can be many ranges in the real data set).

I have written an example to show the right way to make the calculation. In the bottom table I have included the desired result.

The logic is that corn should be deducted 5.29 from 1 to 10 and then (7.37+2.9) from 11 to 20.

Same logic applies  to "apple", but the structure of from-to is slightly different, i.e. ranging from 1-20 and 11-20. When the quantity is <=10 the deduction is 5.31 and if quantity is 11-15, the discounts must be added together (5.31+2.34). The ranges can overlap e.g. deductions for 1-20, 10-20 and 15-25 all apply if the quantity is 17.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Example data:

```
candy   qty_from    qty_to  reason  deduction
corn    1           10      smell   -5.29
corn    10          20      smell   -7.37
corn    10          20      work    -2.90
apple   1           20      smell   -5.31
apple   10          20      work    -2.34
apple   15          25      smell   -1.00
apple   75          110     work    -2.00

data = {'candy':['corn','corn','corn','apple','apple','apple','apple'],
    'qty_from':[1,10,10,1,10,15,75],
    'qty_to':[10,20,20,20,20,25,110],
    'reason':['smell','smell','work','smell','work','smell','work'],
    'deduction':[-5.29,-7.37,-2.9,-5.31,-2.34,-1,-2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Example of results wanted:

```
candy   range   deduction
corn    1-10    -5.29
corn    10-20   -10.27
apple   1-10    -5.31
apple   10-15   -7.65
apple   15-20   -8.65
apple   20-25   -1.00
apple   75-110  -2.00

result_data = 
{'candy':'corn','corn','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple'],
 'range':['1-10','10-20','1-10','10-15','15-20','20-25','75-110'],
 'deduction':[-5.29,-10.27,-5.31,-7.65,-8.65,-1,-2]}

results = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
```

EDIT, why groupby does not work:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['candy','qty_from','qty_to'])['deduction'].sum())


candy   qty_from    qty_to  deduction
apple   1           20      -5.31
        10          20      -2.34
        15          25      -1.00
        75          110     -2.00
corn    1           10      -5.29
        10          20      -10.27
```

E.g. value for apple 10-20 is not correct!

Comment: so you want a grouby candy, max and min and then concatenate two columns into a string?

Comment: Groupby (or pivot_table) doesn't do the trick, unfortunately. I will edit for details.

Comment: Is it always guaranteed that two ranges only overlap if they're identical? In other words, can we assume that if "10-20" exists, then there definitely won't be a "15-25"?

Comment: No, there could be a 15-25 (from reason "work" and "smell" respectively). I hope it will not be the case the the real use-case, but it is actually possible.

Comment: If there are `15-25`, will the thresholds be still `1, 10, 20`? or will they be `1, 10, 15, 20, 25`?

Comment: It will be added. So if there is a deduction for 10-15 and 10-20 and the quantity is 12, then the two deductions will be added.

Comment: If there are overlapping ranges, then this seems quite tricky. The ranges in the results won't necessarily be the same as the ranges in the input. For inputs "10-20" and "15-25", the output would have the ranges 10-15, 15-20, and 20-25. I don't think you can accomplish that with just `groupby`.

Comment: *the quantity is 12, then the two deductions will be added* -- now it's sounds like an `xy` problem. Do you have another table with `quantity` and trying to get the total deduction from it?

Comment: Is the qty_from equal to 1 when 1 and then add 1 if greater than 1. So Range 1, 10 is quantities between 1 and 10 inclusive, while Range 10, 20 is 11 to 20 inclusive?

Comment: @QuangHoang "reason" in the df is actually two separate tables that has been added together (pd.concat). In real life the deduction can either be given separately (to a user) or to a group (of users). If a customer has a deduction on a group and individual level, the deductions must be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as it is now, can be solved with `pd.IntervalIndex`:

```
# get list of all the thresholds
thresh = sorted(set(df[['qty_from', 'qty_to']].values.ravel()))

# all cuts
cuts = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(thresh[:-1], thresh[1:])

# intervals of the quantities
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(a,b) for a,b in zip(df.qty_from, df.qty_to)] )

# overlapings
intersects = pd.DataFrame([[t.overlaps(i) for i in intervals] for t in cuts],
                         index=cuts,
                         columns=df.index)
# get the sum:
intersects.mul(df.deduction).groupby(df.candy, axis=1).sum().unstack()
```

Output:

```
candy          
apple  (1, 10]     -5.31
       (10, 20]    -7.65
corn   (1, 10]     -5.29
       (10, 20]   -10.27
dtype: float64
```

Update: Instead of `t.overlaps(i)`, you can use the custom function:

```
def overlaps(t,i):
    endpoints = (t.left, t.right, i.left, i.right)
    l,r = min(endpoints), max(endpoints)

    return (r-l < (t.length) + (i.length))
```

Comment: For me this just result in: "AttributeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object has no attribute 'overlaps'" ?

Comment: Works fine for pandas 0.24.2. It's new in 0.24.0, so I guess you have a lower version.

Comment: Running '0.23.4'. Cannot upgrade (enterprise laptop, have to wait for release).

Comment: Write your own overlap function?

Comment: Ehmm... I don't know how to? :-/

Comment: If you can help with rewriting the [[t.overlaps(i) for i in intervals] for t in cuts] part of the code, I would be very grateful. I am eager to try this code on my data set, as it the other solution doesn't do the trick (yet at least).

Comment: Thanks!! :-) I will have a look at the outputs as soon as I get a chance! :-)

Comment: This looks very promising. In the test data set, there is only one hurdle left (crossing fingers, applying to real data set in a couple of hours). I now have a dataframe based on the following dict. "corn" (10, 15] and (15-20] have the same deduction. Any easy way of having this as (10, 20] instead?

Comment: {'candy': {0: 'apple',
  1: 'apple',
  2: 'apple',
  3: 'apple',
  5: 'apple',
  6: 'corn',
  7: 'corn',
  8: 'corn'},
 'range': {0: Interval(1, 10, closed='right'),
  1: Interval(10, 15, closed='right'),
  2: Interval(15, 20, closed='right'),
  3: Interval(20, 25, closed='right'),
  5: Interval(75, 110, closed='right'),
  6: Interval(1, 10, closed='right'),
  7: Interval(10, 15, closed='right'),
  8: Interval(15, 20, closed='right')},
 'deduction': {0: -5.31,
  1: -7.6499999999999995,
  2: -8.649999999999999,
  3: -1.0,
  5: -2.0,
  6: -5.29,
  7: -10.27,
  8: -10.27}}

Comment: I made a simple solution:

Comment: mul1 = df.drop_duplicates(['candy','deduction'],'first')
mul1.rename(columns={'range':'range_first'}, inplace = True)
mul2 = df.drop_duplicates(['candy','deduction'],'last')
mul2.rename(columns={'range':'range_last'}, inplace = True)
mul3 = mul1.merge(mul2, how = 'outer')

Comment: def first_last(df):
    df['range2'] = df['range_last'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(',')[1])
    df['range1'] = df['range_first'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(',')[0])
    df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x:  x.range1 + ',' + x.range2 if x.range_first != x.range_last else x.range_first, axis = 1)
    df.drop(['range_first','range_last','range1','range2'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    df = df[['candy','range','deduction']]
    return df
mul4 = first_last(mul3) 
mul4

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what appears to be confusing your coding is that you have two different rules for your desired results: for `corn`, you want to group by `candy`, `qty_to`, and `qty_from` and sum the `deduction` for each group; for `apple`, you want to calculate a cumulative sum. You *could* write code to account for this, but it seems like a fundamentally incorrect way to structure the inputs, which is making subsequent tasks more complicated than it should be.

That said -- and with a large caveat that this works based on the example in the OP, but may not be extensible, as it's not clear what the full set of data / decision rules is --

```
corn = df.loc[df['candy'] == 'corn'].groupby(['candy','qty_from','qty_to'], as_index=False)['deduction'].sum()
apple = df.loc[df['candy'] == 'apple', ['candy', 'qty_from', 'qty_to', 'deduction']].copy()
apple['deduction'] = apple['deduction'].cumsum()
df_new = corn.append(apple, sort=False)
```

gives the desired result posted in the OP:

```
   candy  qty_from  qty_to  deduction
0   corn         1      10      -5.29
1   corn        10      20     -10.27
3  apple         1      20      -5.31
4  apple        10      20      -7.65
```

Comment: I agree that the input structure is problematic - but the real data set is output from an ERP system, so not much I can do. This solution seem to work fine with two "candy"; but what about 25k or even 50k different variables?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a couple answers, but I had a good time with this brain teaser, so I'll throw mine into the mix. It involves generating different dataframes for values greater than ten and those less than or equal to ten, then uses two groupbys to sum the data twice. The final step is to clear up the extra index used:

```
# Making temporary new dataframe with range column
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
temp_df[['candy', 'qty_to', 'deduction']] = df[['candy', 'qty_to', 'deduction']]
temp_df['range'] = df['qty_from'].astype(str) + '-' + df['qty_to'].astype(str)

# Separating the dataframes to define ranges above ten:
under_10 = temp_df[temp_df['qty_to'] <=10]
over_10 = temp_df[temp_df['qty_to'] > 10]
under_10['under_over'] = ['under'] * under_10.shape[0]
over_10['under_over'] = ['over'] * over_10.shape[0]
new_df = under_10.append(over_10)
new_df.drop('qty_to', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Grouping range, then whether the value is above 10 or not
final_df = new_df.groupby(axis=0, by=['candy', 'range', 'under_over']).sum().groupby(['candy','under_over']).cumsum()

# Dropping the unwanted 'under_over' column
temp_deduction = list(final_df['deduction'])
index = final_df.index.droplevel(level=2)
final_df = final_df.reindex(index=index)
final_df['deduction'] = temp_deduction
```

[final_df then looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSQqF.png)

Comment: This is probably fine for a few interval ranges. But I also need to be able to account for additional ranges being added. Even random ranges like 78-154 could suddenly appear in the real data set.

Comment: So do you need to add up items only that share a range? For example, what is the desired output of the following df: data = {'candy':['corn','corn','corn','apple','apple', 'corn','apple'],
        'qty_from':[1,10,10,1,10,75,15],
        'qty_to':[10,20,20,20,20,150,30],
        'reason':['smell','smell','work','smell','work','smell','work'],
        'deduction':[-5.29,-7.37,-2.9,-5.31,-2.34,-12,-4]} ? My code gives [this](https://i.imgur.com/Xs8a1ip.png) result.

Comment: No, this gives an incorrect sum. If quantity == 80, then the deduction is only -12 (as it is only within the new range of 75-150, not any of the others), not -22.27. The deduction is only given within the specified quantities, not as an unconditional accumulative sum as quantities are added. Hope this makes sense?